# Error when retrieving Date from datetime.date object in Python

Tags: python, mysql, anaconda, pymysql

I want to retrieve date in the format of "May 01 2009" from datetime.date object. I have a table stored in MySQL database. It has Date column, and Time Column separately. Date in table is of the format,

```
2009-05-01
```

I have connected to MySQL server using PyMySQL module,

```
conn = pymysql.connect("localhost", "root", "cloudera", "streaming")
cursor = conn.cursor()
sql = "select * from table1 limit 5;"
cursor.execute(sql)
row = cursor.fetchone()
row[0]
```

Output is,

```
datetime.date(2009, 5, 1)
```

When I try the below command to extract the date in the way I want,

```
datetime.date.strftime("%b %d %Y", row[0])
```

I get an error as,

```
TypeError: descriptor 'strftime' requires a 'datetime.date' object but received a 'str'
```

I just don't get it, when datetime.date object is provided, it raises an error.
Can anyone please help me. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`strftime` is a instance method of `date` objects, not a separate function:

```
print(row[0].strftime("%b %d %Y"))
```

The error message is trying to tell you that you're calling the uninstanced method (descriptor) from the `date` class directly, without passing an instance as first parameter.

For more info check [date objects documentation](https://docs.python.org/3/library/datetime.html#date-objects).

Answer (score 0):

It's a datetime.date object. It has a **str**() method which will solve your problem.

```
import datetime
date=datetime.date(2009,5,1)
datetime.date(2009, 5, 1)
str(d)
```

will result as 
'2009-05-01'

Comment: Thank you so much. Your answer helped me a lot.

Comment: You  should never call the `__str__` method directly. If you want to convert something to string just call `str(x)`